# how to store a number for everyone user using django

Tags: django, model

model.py:

```
class Tribes(Group):

    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='tribes', verbose_name=_('members'))
```

i want to store a number in  a  int field ,and a user can has many this number.

how to write this model ??

thanks

(i hate sql :( )

**updated**

this is my code:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    LatLng = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a list of numbers for each user. You can implement that as a normal ForeignKey-relationship or serialize the list somehow.

Using a ForeignKey, you just create another model:

```
class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

You can then get a users AnotherModel-set with the automatic `user.anothermodel_set` RelatedManager (if user is a User instance):

```
user_numbers = [x.number for x in user.anothermodel_set.all()]
```

If you just want to store a bunch of numbers for one users (and don't need to ever run a query on them), you can serialize a list using pickle or something similar.

Given the code you supplied, I'm not entirely sure what you're doing. Is Position the number you want to store for each user? If so, you've done what I did first. Just add a number field to your Position model and you can get a User's position_set with `user.position_set`. I'm not sure it makes sense to have many positions for one user, however. Could you please provide some more code or detail into what you're doing?